# Search Filter Recycler Adapter

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, adapter, searchview

I'm trying to perform a search on my recycler adapter when onQueryTextChange
 as shown below.

```
newText = newText.toLowerCase();
List<HymnDataModel> search_list = new ArrayList<>();

 for(HymnDataModel hymnDataModel : hymnDataList){
                String hymn_title = hymnDataModel.getHymnTitle().toLowerCase();
                String hymn_subTitle = hymnDataModel.getHymnSubTitle().toLowerCase();
                if (hymn_title.contains(newText) || hymn_subTitle.contains(newText)){
                    search_list.add(hymnDataModel);
                }
            }
```

And i filter the Adapter using the setFilter.

```
adapterRV.setFilter(search_list);
```

This is the setFilter function in my Adapter

```
public void setFilter(List<HymnDataModel> search_list) {
    mHymnsList = new ArrayList<>();
    mHymnsList.addAll(search_list);
    //notify to reload
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

The search works just fine, onQueryTextChange
, but after filtering the Adapter and displaying on the RecyclerView, when i click on the filtered/searched item on my recyclerview, it doesn't open that particular item, instead, it  opens another item that's not on the filtered list.

Comment: Add your entire adapter code stuff here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead.Assign search_list to the existing array List.

```
public void setFilter(List<HymnDataModel> search_list) {
    mHymnsList = search_list;
    //notify to reload 
    notifyDataSetChanged(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are appending Filtered data item's in your `Arraylist` that's why your adapter display  item that's not on the filtered list. try this clear your `Arraylist` before adding Filtered item in your `Arraylist`

Try this

```
public void setFilter(List<HymnDataModel> search_list) {
    mHymnsList.clear();
    mHymnsList.addAll(search_list);

    or 
     mHymnsList = search_list;

    //notify to reload
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```